# Bootstrap radio button height

Tags: css, radio-button, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap radio buttons set to 200px width. When text inside the button is longer than that it runs onto 2 lines so the button height changes. How can I get the other buttons displayed to also scale to the same height?

[image: buttons]

[image: button2]

```
 <!-- question 7 -->
                  <div class="row mb-4">
                    <div class="btn-group justify-content-center" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                      <div class="row"><p><strong style="display: inline">Q7</strong> {{ post.question7 }}</p></div></div>
                      <div class="row justify-content-center mx-auto">
                        {% if post.url7 %}
                    <div class="row"><img class="maths" src="static/test/{{ post.url7 }}"></div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <fieldset id="group7">
                      <div class="form-check-inline spelling_button p-0 mb-1 mx-auto"><input type="radio" class="btn-check" id="q7a" name="options7" value="ae" autocomplete="off" required>
                        <label class="btn btn btn-outline-primary quiz" for="q7a"><strong style="display: inline">A:</strong> {{ post.ae }}</label></div>
                      <div class="form-check-inline spelling_button p-0 mb-1 mx-auto"><input type="radio" class="btn-check" id="q7b" name="options7" value="af" autocomplete="off">
                        <label class="btn btn btn-outline-primary quiz" for="q7b"><strong style="display: inline">B:</strong> {{ post.af }}</label></div>
                        <div class="form-check-inline spelling_button p-0 mb-1 mx-auto"><input type="radio" class="btn-check" id="q7c" name="options7" value="ag" autocomplete="off">
                          <label class="btn btn btn-outline-primary quiz" for="q7c"><strong style="display: inline">C:</strong> {{ post.ag }}</label></div>
                          <div class="form-check-inline spelling_button p-0 mb-1 mx-auto"><input type="radio" class="btn-check" id="q7d" name="options7" value="ah" autocomplete="off">
                            <label class="btn btn btn-outline-primary quiz" for="q7d"><strong style="display: inline">D:</strong> {{ post.ah }}</label></div>
                            <div class="form-check-inline spelling_button p-0 mb-1 mx-auto"><input type="radio" class="btn-check" id="q7e" name="options7" value="ai" autocomplete="off">
                              <label class="btn btn btn-outline-primary quiz" for="q7e"><strong style="display: inline">E:</strong> {{ post.ai }}</label></div>
                            </fieldset>
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give min-height property so the buttons are same size. You can do it by adding class or inline:

```
<div class="form-check-inline spelling_button p-0 mb-1 mx-auto" style="min-height: 60px;">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" id="q7a" name="options7" value="ae" autocomplete="off" required >
  <label class="btn btn btn-outline-primary quiz" for="q7a">
    <strong style="display: inline">A:</strong> 
    {{ post.ae }}
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to just add 60px below. Also, I don't want the buttons to be a minimum height, I want them all to be the exact same height as the buttons in the row, some rows might have a button where the text doesn't fit on the first line of a button where another row might have the text of all buttons all fit on the first line.

Comment: 60px was just example. You can check height of all the buttons in the row with .offsetHeight take the largest value and set min-height to LargestButton.offsetHeight

Comment: Hear is example of 2 buttons, for more you should use arrays: let button1Height=document.getElementsByClassName('spelling_button')[0].offsetHeight;
let button2Height=document.getElementsByClassName('spelling_button')[1].offsetHeight;

if (button1Height<button2Height){
    button1Height = button2Height
}

document.getElementsByClassName('spelling_button')[0].style.height = button1Height + 'px';
document.getElementsByClassName('spelling_button')[1].style.height = button1Height + 'px';